# Google's strange Source Code

Tags: google-search

Why does the source code of Google's main page look so strange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it was obfuscated to decrease it's size

Comment: the term you're looking for here is "minified". It's quite a common technique for Javascript these days.

Answer (score 0):

The source code was "minified" and as a consequence, it was also "obfuscated". The main reason was to reduce the size but also optimize the code.

For example, Google has developed the Closure Tools which contain the Closure Compiler. It allows to compile the Javascript source code in order to produce a faster Javascript code. It removes dead code, rewrite some code and minimize the remaining parts. The code will both run faster and be smaller to load.

[The wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29)